# Record Rule for user groups in openerp

Tags: odoo

I have created a new module in openerp which contain consumption details related to each project.
I have created two user groups for my module (user,manager).User can create consumption details of project and he can see only consumption details which he has created.
I give the permission like this

```
<record id="property_rule_mat_mgmt_user" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">Material Manage Rule</field>
            <field model="ir.model" name="model_id" ref="model_mat_mgmt"/>
            <field name="domain_force">[('create_uid','=',user.id)]</field>
        </record>
```

It is working fine

Similarly if I assign a user as manager of my module he can see all consumption details of projects,in which he is member or manager.How to write the rule, I tried different ways but can't find a proper rule.

This is one of the rule I have tried

```
<record id="property_rule_mat_mgmt_manager" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">Material Manage manager Rule</field>
            <field model="ir.model" name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_project"/>
            <field name="domain_force">['|',('user_id','=',False),('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, it would have been be easier to answer if you could give the details of your model, specifically the `mat.mgmt` one. Perhaps that's why there was no answer yet.

Let's say you have a many2one relationship between `mat.mgmt` and `project.project` named `project_id`, you could then use something like this:

```
<record id="property_rule_mat_mgmt_manager" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">Material Manage manager Rule</field>
            <field model="ir.model" name="model_id" ref="model_mat_mgmt"/>
            <field name="domain_force">['|',('project_id.user_id','=',False),('project_id.user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
</record>
```

Notice that the model is still `model_mat_mgmt` as this is the model on which the filtering is applied. You didn't want to filter projects but `mat.mgmt` if I understand correctly your question.

Comment: I have change the group of procurement tab for this " Remove access to sales managers & users to see the procurements tab in products + access to information on this procurement tab (supplier's name, purchase prices, etc)
" but i also lost procurement tab from all view mean from purchase and warehouse i use this code "group=sale.group_manager"

Answer (score 0):

```
<record id="user_record_rule_id" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Record Rule Name</field>
    <field model="ir.model" name="model_id" ref="model_my_model_name"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('create_uid', '=', user.id)]</field>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('group_user'))]"/>
</record>

<record id="manager_record_rule_id" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Record Rule Name</field>
    <field model="ir.model" name="model_id" ref="model_my_model_name"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[]</field>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('group_manager'))]"/>
</record>
```

Try above code:

manager group should be inherited from user group

example:

```
<record id="group_user" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">User</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_name"/>
</record>
<record id="group_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Manager</field>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_user'))]"/>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_exit_category"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

Explanation:

User can create the record(s) as well as can view his record(s) only

but manager can see all the user's record(s) as well as he can create & view his own record(s)